# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в форме пропечатывался тэг?

Tags: html, javascript, css, php

Всем привет. Меня интересует следующее.

Как можно сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в форме пропечатывался тэг? Пример - форма публикации вопроса на хэшкоде. Нажимаем на кнопку (B, I и т.д.) и печатаются символы, но текст не становится жирным или курсивным.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно, при нажатии кнопки `B, I, etc`, получить выделенный текст в `textarea` или другом инпуте и обернуть его в нужный вам тег(в зависимости от нажатой кнопки)

Посмотрите вот этот `jQuery` плагин: [`jQuery.selection`](http://madapaja.github.io/jquery.selection/#tab-demo-textarea-js). Думаю он должен Вам подойти.